# vkontakte sharing messages in wall in android?

Tags: android, vk

i need to share messages in vkontakte and post those messages in wall. please any one help me solve this

Thanks in advance
harish

Comment: from the http://vk.com/developers.php?id=-1_37230422&s=1  .. created a App_id and tried out sample from https://github.com/StonerHawk/Vkontakte-Android-SDK. but its not working at all

Comment: @harish Hello Harish, your problem is solved or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this: http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/129648/ for an API implementation or just use Intent.ACTION_SEND in your app to let the official VK Android app handle your content (just like with email or twitter). Here's a useful link that describes how to filter out unwanted ACTION_SEND handlers if you want your app to share stuff via VK only: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8950207/375929

Comment: Hello Ivan, I am using android sdk for integrate vkontakte in my application but i do not know how to upload photo to vkontakte, please help me.

Comment: @DipakKeshariya Well, the only way I know of is to use the standard share workflow - just as with any other photo, VK can handle those just as Twitter or FB can. If you want to only let VK handle your photo sharing intent, you can filter others out by specifying the package name of VK, check this for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308666/how-to-force-share-intent-to-open-a-specific-app

Comment: @DipakKeshariya but then again, that's not exactly what you'd call using VK api, that's just generic approach. I havent done that through the api, so you're on your own there, but just google around - i'm sure if it's possible it's been done many times and you'll find some resources on it.

Comment: Ivan Bartsov, can u please help with share in VK only? Please, see: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/493651/17111

Answer (score 2):

We posted and SDK just recently. You can try, there's a sample that exactly posts to wall. https://github.com/thest1/Android-VKontakte-SDK  http://habrahabr.ru/post/143339/

Comment: Hello Fedor, I am using android sdk for integrate vkontakte in my application but i do not know how to upload photo to vkontakte, please help me.

Comment: Do you have perhaps a simple Intent handling for going directly to a specific VK-friend ? For example, in LinkedIn, you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23885121/878126 , and in Facebook, you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13107858/878126